# Error: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset

After a long time away from .Net typed datasets I had to work on a legacy project and I have fallen foul of the

`Error: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records`

when trying to load a single record by ID, and then update a single field in that record.

Answer (score 1):

I first ruled out that there was definitely no way another system or user could be updating the record "underneath" my code causing the issue.

I then ruled out data types and rounding were not causing the issue, as i understand that subtle differences of how different systems handle the rounding of floats can cause this reported error message.

I then ruled out "nullable" fields were not causing issues.

What it actually turned out to be, was an error of my own making in my stored procedure. Although it appeared to be returning all of the data I needed to load the typed dataset I had not included the primary key field, so when I stepped through my code the primary field had a value of "-1".

I assume this caused the data adapter some issues. I'm surprised that the error manifested as a concurrency issue. I'd have expected a more informative message for trying to update a record without a key to identify the record!

Correcting my "select for ID" stored procedure to return the ID field as well as all of the more *interesting* fields resolved the issue when the `Update` method was called on the adapter.